# formulario ler banco de dados

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá Pessoal estou tentando fazer um formulário ler opções do banco de dados MySql, porém a linha de código a baixo me mostra apenas a palavra "Array".

Qual é meu erro nessa linha? Alguém pode me ajudar.

```
<form id="cadastro" action= "cadastroprodutos.php" method="post">
<p>Codigo<input type="text" name="codigo"size='14' maxlength="14"   placeholder="Codigo"/></p>
Descrição<input type="text" name="descricao"size='50' maxlength="50" placeholder="Descrição"/>
<p>Cores<input type="text" name="cor"size="12" maxlength="12"  placeholder="Cor"/>
Grupo <input list="grupo" name="grupo" size="10"/>

<?php
  $sql= mysqli_query($conn,"select tipo from grupodeprodutos order by tipo");
    $resp=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
      echo "<datalist id='grupo'><option value='$resp'></datalist>";

?>
Marca<input type="text" name="marca"size='20' maxlength="20" placeholder="Marca"/>
Preço<input type="text" name="preco"size='20' maxlength="20" placeholder="Preço"/></p>
<fieldset><legend>Campos Exclusivos para Moveis</legend> 
<p>Valor de montagem:<input type="text" name="valorm"size='6'maxlength="6" placeholder="Valor de Montagem" value='' OnKeyPress="formatar('R$###,##' this)"/></fieldset></p>
<input type="submit"id="botao" name="botaoo" value="Salvar"/>
</form>
```

Modifiquei a código para esse padrão.Conforme me foi explicado abaixo.

```
Grupo <input list="grupo" name="grupo" size="10"/>
<?php
$sql= mysqli_query($conn,"select tipo from grupodeprodutos order by tipo");
while ($resp = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {

    echo "<datalist id='grupo'><option value='" . $resp[0] . "'>    </datalist>";
}
?>
```

Agora  os dados são coletados, mas é sempre exibido o ultimo item da tabela, sendo que preciso que todos apareçam. Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque a variável $resp do seu código é um array, que foi retornado pela função `mysqli_fetch_row` e quando se tenta imprimir na tela um `Array`, o PHP imprimi uma string 'Array', não o que ele contém.

Para pode imprimir o resultado na tela, de acordo com seu código, você pode fazer da seguinte forma, usando o laço `while`:

```
<?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"select tipo from grupodeprodutos order by tipo");

    echo "<datalist id='grupo'>";

    while ($resp = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $resp[0] . "'>";
    }

    echo "</datalist>";
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado suas dicas foram muito úteis, porém não funcionou de primeiro momento. Mas mudei ($resp = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) para ($resp = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) e executou perfeitamente.

Comment: Oi Amigo tive o problema depois, o formulário só exibi o ultimo item da tabela

Answer (score 0):

Resolve todos os problemas trocando o fomato do campo para:

```
<select name="grupo"/>
<?php
$sql= mysqli_query($conn,"select tipo from grupodeprodutos order by tipo");
while ($resp = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {

     $group=$resp['tipo'];

    echo "<option value='$group'>$group</option>";
}

?>
</select>
```

Na forma antiga a função executa, mas o `<datalist>` só localiza o primeiro dado informado.